# how to get a php function with html inside

Tags: php, html

I am trying to combine html and php to get a function.

```
<?php 
function display_text()
{
        $handle_text = '
        <div class="container">'.
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row); .'

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        '. echo $row['body']; .'
                    </div>
                </div> '.
        } .'
        </div>';

        return $handle_text ;
}
?>
```

However I get an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in C:\wamp64`. 
How could I manage it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: learn the basics of PHP, then you will figure out super easily

Comment: You can't just continue on the addition, you will need to add each part as you go along using `$handle_text .=...`

Comment: You're trying to concatenate *the loop itself* to the string.  A loop doesn't return a value.  Instead, concatenate to the string *within* the loop.  So first define the container div string, then append each row within the loop, then after the loop concatenate the closing div.

Comment: You can't concatenate a string with a while statement. Consider storing the output of the loop in a variable then using it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.